# A question on Lebesgue measure and its absolutely continuous measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ be a measure absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

Suppose for Lebesgue measurable sets $X_n$, $n=1,2,...$,

$\lambda(X_n)=1/n$.

Do we have  $\mu(X_n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: this seems to be thinking of a concept like contiguity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguity_(probability_theory))

Answer (score 11):

Define $\mu$ on the Lebesgue measurable sets by
$$\mu(E)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\ \lambda(E)=0,\\
\infty & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
The fact that this is a measure follows by using that $\lambda(\emptyset)=0$ and $\lambda(\cup_n E_n)=0$ iff $\lambda(E_n)=0$ for each $n$. Clearly $\mu \ll \lambda$. However $\mu(X_n) = \infty$ for every $n$.

If $\mu$ is assumed to be finite, then it is true. In fact, we have the following theorem (Theorem 3.5 from Folland's Real Analysis).

> **Theorem.** Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure and $\mu$ a positive measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$. Then $\nu \ll \mu$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\nu(E)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$.

The reverse direction is easy, and the forward direction follows from a standard argument by contradiction using continuity from above.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the measure $\mu(dx) = |x| \, \lambda(dx)$ and $X_n = [n,n+\frac{1}{n}]$. Then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$ but

$$ \mu(X_n) = \int_{X_n} |x| \, dx \geq 1. $$

Comment: where does this notation $\mu(dx)$ come from?

Comment: @zhw., Not sure what you are asking, but this is a common shorthand for the measure defined by $\mu(B) = \int_{B} |x| \, \lambda(dx)$.

Comment: OK, never seen it before, and it seems strange to me.

Comment: @zhw., This style of notation is often used by probabilist, for instance, expressions like $\mathbb{P}(X \in dx) = f(x) \, dx$ are not uncommon in probability theory. But it seems to me that expressions like $d\mu(x) = |x| \, d\lambda(x)$ are more commonly used in analysis.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6):

Unless $\mu$ is a finite measure this is, in general, not true. Consider for instance

$$\mu(B) := \int_{B \cap (0,\infty)} x \, \lambda(dx)$$

and

$$X_n := \left[n, n+ \frac{1}{n} \right],$$

then

$$\mu(X_n) = \int_n^{n+1/n} x \, \lambda(dx) \geq n \int_{n}^{n+1/n} \, \lambda(dx) = 1;$$

in particular $\mu(X_n)$ does **not** converge to $0$.